# Распарсить массив Python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!

Есть переменная содержащая массив

```
rows_index = [2,3,7]
```

Данные которые попадают в данную переменную динамические...

Нужно на выходе получить из данного массива переменные

```
a = 2
b = 2
a = 3
b = 3
a = 7
b = 7
```

Comment: опишите алгоритм получения данных - почему именно так у вас должно получаться на выходе?

Comment: я спросил "почему", а не "для чего". почему должно получится так, как вы написали?

Comment: Что бы дальше использовать эти данные rows_index это результат поиска строки в гугл таблице т.е. данные которые мне нужно находятся в строках 2 3 и 7. Почему нужны переменные (a и b) эти данные я буду использовать чтобы задать диапазон для вывода содержания строк таблицы.. Надеюсь получилось объяснить)

Comment: Сори в 1-м комментарии я не дописал нажал ентр и сообщение ушло)

Comment: Также есть переменная quantity которая показывает количество элементов в массиве (на всякий случай)

Comment: В цикле a=r[i], b=r[i]?

Comment: плз. напишите чуть подробнее

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, подойдёт ли Вам именно такой вариант, но:

```
rows_index = [2,3,7]

a = ''
b = ''

for i in rows_index:
    a = i
    b = i
    print('a:', a, 'b:', b)
```

В каждой итерации цикла переменные а и в будут принимать значение элемента списка.

Comment: Если сделать вот так то самое то! Спасибо
    print('a =', a)
    print('b =', b)

Answer (score 0):

```
quantity = 3
rows_index = [2,3,7]

for i in range(0, quantity):
    print('a =', rows_index[i])
    print('b =', rows_index[i])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вы также можете количество элементов не подсчитывать вручную, а сделать: quantity = len(rows_index)